# specifying node.js dependency in both "devDependencies" and "peerDependencies"

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, dependencies

I just found out in grunt-contrib-clean package.json file, that it has dependency on *grunt* that is stated in both sections: `devDependencies` and `peerDependencies`, 
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean/blob/master/package.json#L25-L34:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-internal": "^0.4.10",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "^0.4.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "grunt": ">=0.4.0"
  },
```

Does that make any sense? Especially, that there are different versions stated? Is it an unnoticed mistake?

edit: also posted a [github issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean/issues/67).

Answer (score 1):

So according; https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean/issues/67:

> Read up on the difference of devDependencies and peerDependencies. The devDep >is for the actual grunt dep we use for testing and the peerDep is for noting >which grunt version the plugin works with. Both resolve to the same version.